# Where error in crop image?

Tags: php, image, crop

*Good day.*

*i have problem with a crop image.*

**original image:**

[image: original]

**after use code i give next image:**

[image: last]

**Code for crop image:**

```
$pathTemp = '../Images/Temp/';
$path = '../Images/';
$pathCrop = '../Images/Crop/';


if($image=='0'){die('error_image');}
if (!copy($pathTemp.$image, $path.$image)){die('error_image');}

$ext_arr = explode('.',$image);
$ext = $ext_arr[1];

$jpeg_quality = 90;
$src = $pathCrop.$image;

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor($_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);

imagecopyresized($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x1'],$_POST['y1'],170,110,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

imagejpeg($dst_r,$pathCrop.time().'.jpg',$jpeg_quality);
```

***Tell me please where i have error?***

***Why i get bad end image?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script works, I think that your problem is the location of the original image.

Isn't your original image supposed to be in the `$path` folder ?
You're looking for it in the `$pathCrop` folder.

```
$src = $pathCrop.$image;
```

Then `$img_r` is empty, so when you copy it to `$dst_r` you have a black image.

Try replacing

```
$src = $pathCrop.$image;
```

by

```
$src = $path.$image;
```

Comment: No problem ! This was my first answer ever ;)